# Can plants survive indefinitely without external supply of gases at compensation point?

Tags: photosynthesis

During photosynthesis, there is a point at which the light intensity is such that the rate of photosynthesis exactly matches the rate of respiration called the [compensation point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensation_point). What this means is that the plant can essentially utilize the $\ce{CO_2}$ produced during respiration for photosynthesis and the $\ce{O_2}$ produced during photosynthesis for respiration. But, does this mean, that a plant which has been given an initial supply of $\ce{CO_2}$ and $\ce{O_2}$ and then subsequently put into another gas (still in compensation point light intensity), say nitrogen, can survive indefinitely? (or as long as it's life span).

Answer (score 2):

If the plant is growing the system will fall out of equilibrium due to more carbon going into biomass than oxygen.

Comment: Another concern might be that depending on how much neutral nitrogen there is, the oxygen/CO2 might diffuse into the nitrogen, lowering the available amount.